# stop splash animation through touch event

Tags: iphone, objective-c, touch

In my app I am using animation for splash screen.
this animation stops after a delay is 5 sec. 
But I want that before 5 sec if user interupted(touch) animation should stop.

For animation I am writing:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Array to hold jpg images
    imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:IMAGE_COUNT];

    // Build array of images, cycling through image names

    imageArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"f1.jpg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"f2.jpg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"f3.jpg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"f4.jpg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"f5.jpg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"f6.jpg"], nil];

    // Animated images - centered on screen
    animatedImages = [[UIImageView alloc] 
                      initWithFrame:CGRectMake(
                                               (SCREEN_WIDTH / 2) - (IMAGE_WIDTH / 2), 
                                               (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2) - (IMAGE_HEIGHT / 2) + STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT,
                                               IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT)];
    animatedImages.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:imageArray];

    // One cycle through all the images takes 1.5 seconds
    animatedImages.animationDuration =1;

    // Repeat forever
    animatedImages.animationRepeatCount = -1;

    // Add subview and make window visible
    [window addSubview:animatedImages];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Start it up
    //animatedImages.startAnimating;
    [animatedImages startAnimating];


    // Wait 5 seconds, then stop animation
    [self performSelector:@selector(stopAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];

}

- (void)stopAnimation
{
    [animatedImages stopAnimating];
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: You should reconsider your starting routine, anyway. An App should start as fast as possible in order to let the user experience a "multithreading feeling". Some developers spend days in making App start faster. The animation may be nice, if the user sees it for the first time. After 2 or 3 startups it may be anoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a problem

call `stopAnimation` method in `tochesBegan` method like this

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   YourAppDelegate *obj=(YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   [obj stopAnimation];
}
```

Comment: ok, I implemented but control is not going on touchBegan function. I am writing all above code in appDelegate.

Comment: but the problem is that control is not going on tochesBegan function.  BTW what is going in 1st line.

Comment: since stopAnimation function declares in app delegate class so you need object for that so 1 line make that.

Comment: touchesBegan calls when you touch the view itself in each condition.

Comment: I think you are having any control on your view thats why you cant touch the view.

Comment: ok Thanks! and what I do control is not going on tochesBegan function.

Comment: but on appDelegate how can I have any control, I have done all above code in appDelegate. Here in appDelegate firstly the animation will occure then only view will load.for animation I have used many full screen images.

Comment: you need UIView or UIViewController below the images for touch methods as i believe.try to make a viewContoller and post this code in that method only add that view here on window.

Comment: see this http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/01/15/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-part-1/ it shows how you can use touches method.

Comment: you need make UIViewController and make animation on that view.currently you working on window so there you cant access these methods.